# UE5 SIGSEGV: invalid attempt to write memory at address 0x0000000000000003 Exception on Project Startup

Tags: linux, crash, segmentation-fault, fedora, unreal-engine5

I've just built Unreal Engine (release branch) from source on Fedora 34.
Every time I try to open a Project it crashes with the SIGSEGV Exception. I saw on another post in the UE forums that it is fixed since 4.15, but this doesn't seem to be the case for 5.0.1. I've got an i7-4790, 8GB RAM and Intel HD Graphics. I also do not have any privileges on this machine.

From CrashContext.runtime-xml:

```
<ErrorMessage>Fatal error: [File:./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanUtil.cpp] [Line: 965] Result failed, VkResult=-4 at ./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanMemory.cpp:4793 with error VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST &lt;&lt; callstack too long &gt;&gt;</ErrorMessage>
```

Logs:

```
[2022.05.12-06.59.40:566][  0]LogMaterial: Display: Missing cached shadermap for LevelGridMaterial2 in VULKAN_SM5, Default, SM5 (DDC key hash: 753C5792B90529F682DC43446F35BE7BF06C4464), compiling. 
[2022.05.12-06.59.48:600][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Error: Result failed, VkResult=-4
 at ./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanMemory.cpp:4793 
 with error VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST
[2022.05.12-06.59.49:014][  0]LogCore: Error: appError called: Fatal error: [File:./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanUtil.cpp] [Line: 965] 
Result failed, VkResult=-4
 at ./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanMemory.cpp:4793 
 with error VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST
<< callstack too long >>


[2022.05.12-06.59.49:061][  0]LogCore: === Critical error: ===
Unhandled Exception: SIGSEGV: invalid attempt to write memory at address 0x0000000000000003

[2022.05.12-06.59.49:061][  0]LogCore: Fatal error: [File:./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanUtil.cpp] [Line: 965] 
Result failed, VkResult=-4
 at ./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanMemory.cpp:4793 
 with error VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST
```

Callstack:

```
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!VulkanRHI::VerifyVulkanResult(VkResult, char const*, char const*, unsigned int) [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanUtil.cpp:964]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!VulkanRHI::FFenceManager::CheckFenceState(VulkanRHI::FFence*) [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanMemory.cpp:4793]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanCmdBuffer::RefreshFenceStatus() [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanCommandBuffer.cpp:367]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanDevice::WaitUntilIdle() [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanDevice.cpp:1549]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanViewport::DestroySwapchain(FVulkanSwapChainRecreateInfo*) [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanViewport.cpp:700]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!TEnqueueUniqueRenderCommandType<FVulkanDynamicRHI::RHIResizeViewport(FRHIViewport*, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, EPixelFormat)::ResizeViewportName, FVulkanDynamicRHI::RHIResizeViewport(FRHIViewport*, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, EPixelFormat)::$_22>::DoTask(ENamedThreads::Type, TRefCountPtr<FGraphEvent> const&) [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/RenderCore/Public/RenderingThread.h:193]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!TGraphTask<TEnqueueUniqueRenderCommandType<FVulkanDynamicRHI::RHIResizeViewport(FRHIViewport*, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, EPixelFormat)::ResizeViewportName, FVulkanDynamicRHI::RHIResizeViewport(FRHIViewport*, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, EPixelFormat)::$_22> >::ExecuteTask(TArray<FBaseGraphTask*, TSizedDefaultAllocator<32> >&, ENamedThreads::Type, bool) [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Async/TaskGraphInterfaces.h:975]
libUnrealEditor-Core.so!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksNamedThread(int, bool) [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/Core/Private/Async/TaskGraph.cpp:753]
libUnrealEditor-Core.so!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksUntilQuit(int) [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/Core/Private/Async/TaskGraph.cpp:641]
libUnrealEditor-Core.so!FTaskGraphCompatibilityImplementation::ProcessThreadUntilRequestReturn(ENamedThreads::Type) [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/Core/Private/Async/TaskGraph.cpp:2114]
libUnrealEditor-RenderCore.so!RenderingThreadMain(FEvent*) [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/RenderCore/Private/RenderingThread.cpp:380]
libUnrealEditor-RenderCore.so!FRenderingThread::Run() [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/RenderCore/Private/RenderingThread.cpp:544]
libUnrealEditor-Core.so!FRunnableThreadPThread::Run() [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/Core/Private/HAL/PThreadRunnableThread.cpp:25]
libUnrealEditor-Core.so!FRunnableThreadPThread::_ThreadProc(void*) [/home/user/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/HAL/PThreadRunnableThread.h:185]
libpthread.so.0!UnknownFunction(0x92a4)
libc.so.6!clone(+0x42)
```

Here are the full crash files if you need more info:

[Diagnostics](https://pastebin.com/eDZdKZsn)

[Project.log](https://pastebin.com/CRTWfMdc)

[CrashContext.runtime-xml](https://pastebin.com/dpA3sWFF)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. I'm afraid this question is way too broad.